# How to make a vector of elements the pattern of a function?

Tags: functions, function-construction, pattern-matching, vector

if I have an expression that contains a lot of symbolic elements and I would want to make it a function of the vector containing all the elements I've found a solution based on rule delayed:

```
vectelem = ToExpression["q" <> ToString[#]] &;
Mat = Table[vectelem@RandomInteger[{1, 30}], {i, 10}, {j, 10}];
qlist = Array[vectelem, 30];
Fmat[q_] := Mat /. Thread[qlist -> q]
Mat // MatrixForm
Fmat@Range[1, 30] // MatrixForm

{{q11, q23, q2, q27, q3, q14, q7, q12, q16, q7}, {q6, q27, q6, q29, 
  q2, q3, q27, q18, q20, q5}, {q4, q20, q17, q15, q17, q14, q26, q15, 
  q5, q18}, {q16, q10, q30, q10, q4, q13, q24, q6, q28, q21}, {q16, 
  q3, q17, q4, q12, q11, q12, q1, q20, q1}, {q9, q29, q7, q3, q20, 
  q23, q20, q10, q23, q5}, {q7, q28, q27, q4, q19, q26, q12, q30, q6, 
  q1}, {q9, q5, q16, q27, q5, q29, q12, q15, q4, q29}, {q26, q7, q16, 
  q18, q16, q3, q9, q21, q9, q23}, {q13, q9, q16, q6, q29, q6, q6, 
  q19, q21, q2}}

{{11, 23, 2, 27, 3, 14, 7, 12, 16, 7}, {6, 27, 6, 29, 2, 3, 27, 18, 
  20, 5}, {4, 20, 17, 15, 17, 14, 26, 15, 5, 18}, {16, 10, 30, 10, 4, 
  13, 24, 6, 28, 21}, {16, 3, 17, 4, 12, 11, 12, 1, 20, 1}, {9, 29, 7,
   3, 20, 23, 20, 10, 23, 5}, {7, 28, 27, 4, 19, 26, 12, 30, 6, 
  1}, {9, 5, 16, 27, 5, 29, 12, 15, 4, 29}, {26, 7, 16, 18, 16, 3, 9, 
  21, 9, 23}, {13, 9, 16, 6, 29, 6, 6, 19, 21, 2}}
```

Anyway I was asking myself if is there another way that avoid the use of set delayed, in order to get something like:

```
Fmat[{q1_,q2_, ... ,q30_}] = Mat;
```

Without writing all the 30 variables.
Furthermore if I'd want all these variables being numeric ? Is there a way to not append ?NumericQ for each variable ?

Comment: does `patterntest = 
 PatternTest[Pattern@##, NumericQ] & @@@ 
  Array[{Symbol["q" <> ToString@#], Blank[]} &, 30]; 
Fmat2[patterntest] = Mat;
Fmat2@Range[30] // MatrixForm` give what you need?

Comment: or `pattern = 
  Pattern @@@ Array[{Symbol["q" <> ToString@#], Blank[]} &, 30];
Fmat3[p : pattern /; VectorQ[p, NumericQ]] = Mat;
Fmat3@Range[30] // MatrixForm`?

Comment: @kglr you're the king of kings, thank you ! the first answer works pretty well, the second one gives me an error but I didn't investigate, it doesn't matter, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
Mat = Table[vectelem @ RandomInteger[{1, 30}], {i, 10}, {j, 10}];
```

You can use [`Pattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) + [`Condition (/;)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) + [`VectorQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorQ.html) + [`NumericQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html) to define your argument pattern:

```
ClearAll[pattern, Fmat1]

pattern = p : Pattern @@@ Array[{Symbol["q" <> ToString@#], _} &, 30] /; 
   VectorQ[p, NumericQ]; 

Fmat1[pattern] = Mat;
```

If a list of symbols (such as your `qlist`) is already defined you can define `pattern` using

```
p : Thread[Pattern @@ {qlist, _}] /; VectorQ[p, NumericQ] 

% == pattern
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Alternatively, you can use [`Pattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) + [`PatternTest (?)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) + [`NumericQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html)

```
ClearAll[patterntest, Fmat2]

patterntest = Pattern[##]?NumericQ & @@@ Array[{Symbol["q" <> ToString @ #], _} &, 30]; 

Fmat2[patterntest] = Mat;
```

If `qlist` is already defined you can define `patterntest` as:

```
Pattern[##]?NumericQ & @@@ Thread[{qlist, _}]

% == patterntest
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Both give the same result as `Fmat` in OP:

```
Fmat1 @ Range @ 30 == Fmat2 @ Range @ 30 == Fmat @ Range @ 30
```

> ```
> True
> ```